# Overriding Craft Commerce config files

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

Is there a way to override the Craft Commerce config files ?

I'm specifically talking about this one, deep inside the plugin `craft/plugins/commerce/etc/currencies.php`

I'd like to change the default amount of decimals for Euros

Answer (score 1):

For that particular file, the answer is no... not without hacking the core Commerce plugin file, which we don't recommend.

If you think there's a bug in the file, send an email to support@craftcommerce.com.  If you'd like to create a feature request to open up that file so it is configurable, you can do that [here](https://craftcms.uservoice.com/forums/295386-commerce).